# upgrading openssl 0.9.8 to openssl 1.0.1

Tags: php

I would like to add a question installing composer windows 10. I ran the exe file but I receive an error The OpenSSL library (0.9.8y) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1. upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above. Could someone advise me how to upgrade.  I enabled the openssl extension in php.ini but still wont install.

Comment: Which version (and build) of php do you use? Is it necessary to use this specific version? The builds at http://windows.php.net e.g. use `OpenSSL 1.0.1s` for the 5.6.19 x86 TS build and `OpenSSL 1.0.2g` for the 7.0.4 x86 TS build.